# Laravel: How to get data from View/Blade and pass to Controller

Tags: laravel, view, controller

### Tables: Item has boolean "onloan"

Patron(id, name), Item(id, name, onloan), Transactions (patron_id, item_id, loaned, due, returned)

### Relationships:

Patron.php

```php
    public function transaction ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
```

Item.php

```php
    public function transaction ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class);
    }
```

Transaction.php

```php
    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
//        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item','item_id');
    }

    public function patron()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Patron::class);
    }
```

### View: create.blade.php

```php
<label for="item_id">Item</label>
<select name="item_id" id="item_id" class="form-control select2">
  @foreach($items as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">
      {{ $item->barcode }} - {{ $item->name }}
    </option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

### TransactionController.php

This part is where I have problem, Two (2) tables need to be updated.
i.e.
Transactions table: (this part is already working, it's ok)
Name......| Item..........| Loaned.....| Due..
John Doe | Harry Potter | 09/22/20 | 09/23/20

Items table:  (this part I don't know how to add it in the Controller)
Name...........| Onloan
Harry Potter |      1

• how update a foreign table (Items) in this controller so that
the "onloan" value of that $item->id is 1.

```php
    public function store(TransactionRequest $request)
    {
        Transaction::create([
            'patron_id' => $request->patron_id,
            'item_id' => $request->item_id,
            'loaned' => $request->loaned,
            'due' => $request->due,
        ]);
        
        //This is what I tried, but it's not working.
        Item::find($request->item_id);
        $item->update([
            'onloan' => 1,
        ]);
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: isn't the input `item_id` that value?

Comment: Ah. yes. I think you're right. Let me check.
Thank you. You are right! Let me revise my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Υou can write it that way

```
Item::find($request->item_id)->update(['onloan' => 1,]);
```

Create you can also do it

```
 Transaction::create([$request->all()]);
```

Comment: just pass `$request->all()` which is an array, don't wrap it in another array