# Laravel: Create a Table and Update Another Table simultaneously in a Controller

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a new record in Transactions table. And at the same time trying to update another table.

This is what I did.

```php
    public function store(TransactionRequest $request, Item $item)
    {
        //this part works fine
        Transaction::create([
            'patron_id' => $request->patron_id,
            'item_id' => $request->item_id,
            'loaned' => $request->loaned,
            'due' => $request->due,
        ]);

        //THIS PART IS NOT WORKING
        Item::find($request->item_id);
        $item->update([
            'onloan' => "1",
        ]);

        return redirect(route('transactions.index'));

    }
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: so you and "No One" are working on the same exact project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999629/laravel-how-to-get-data-from-view-blade-and-pass-to-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you can try this**

```
 Item::find($request->item_id)
->update([
            'onloan' => "1",
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
Item::find($request->item_id)->update(['onloan' => "1"]);
```

Or, you should write code like this :

```
    $item = Item::find($request->item_id);
    $item->update([
        'onloan' => "1",
    ]);
```